# Recommended control or page flow for iOS app

Tags: ios, iphone, design-patterns, design-guidelines, ui-guidelines

I have an app that implement only two main features - a form to create a table entry and another to look it up with entry screen as login screen. What is the best way to implement the screen flow navigation to these different features? Possible options:

1. Have a new screen after login screen to display a menu to navigate to form or to search screen - just one more screen for navigation purpose is not very intuitive
2. Use tab bar controller - but usually tab bar has minimum of 3 items, in my case its only two
3. Any other recommendations?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One optimal option could be,

1. Post login there should only screen which shows a list of entries with a search bar at the top
2. In the search bar, you can search Entry - `Display the results based on your search query`
3. `Display the selected item` details on based on selection
4. In the navigation bar, you can show one `+` bar button item to add an entry
5. On tapping the `+` item -> `Create Entry Form` -> `Confirmation Screen`

It should look like,

[image]

Comment: This was simple one, for some reason didn't strike me. Thank you!